# Custom Clipper Bezier curve Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently unable to draw a bezier curve.

The output I have right now is :
[image]

The output that I need is :
[image]

What should I add here as bezier values to get the curve?
The code snippet of the custom clipper is:

```
    class OnBoardingClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0.0, size.height * 0.18);
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

P.S. Thanks for reading and apologies in case of bad formatting. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `quadraticBezier` with values of e.g., `(3 / 4 * size.width, size.height * 0.18)` , `(size.width, size.height * 0.05)`.

Code:

```
@override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0.0, size.height * 0.18);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        3 / 4 * size.width, size.height * 0.18, size.width, size.height * 0.05);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    return path;
  }
```

Result:

[image: res]

Comment: You have helped me so much. Thank you for this. You are awesome!