# Flutter : How to implement this custom design using CustomPainter()?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-design

How can I implement below design using CustomPainter()?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Clipper Bezier curve Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63617452/custom-clipper-bezier-curve-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193674/how-to-draw-custom-shapes-in-flutter/67194073#67194073)

if the link answer help, vote up for other to easily view it